# React Redux: Can useDispatch be used to connect to an action creator? If so , how?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

If I'm using a functional component how do I connect to an action creator function using useDispatch, or some other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(actionCreator())
```

it's in the docs

Comment: `dispatch(actions.apiCallBegan({id:1}))` why typescipt throwing error `expected 0 got 1 arg`